# How to arrange the order in stacked graph

Tags: stacked-bar-chart

How to arrange the order in stacked graph, with highest % on top followed by second
Tried many ways but no results , changed the order in data, tried editing data and arrange in order.plese help to understand how this is done using chart filter function

Answer (score 0):

By organizing your data properly, the chart will naturally display the highest percentage on top without needing to use chart filtering or sorting functions.

1. Arrange your data in descending order based on the percentage values you want to display on top.
2. Create or open your stacked graph/chart.
3. The graph should automatically reflect the order of your data, showing the highest percentage on top.